# why we need to add & in decltype(&fun) when fun is a static function?

Tags: c++, decltype

The source code:

```
static bool cmp(pair<int, int>& m, pair<int, int>& n) {
    return m.second > n.second;
}
priority_queue<pair<int, int>, vector<pair<int, int>>, decltype(&cmp)> q(cmp);
```

why we need to add & in decltype(&fun) when fun is a static function?

Comment: `bool(pair<int, int>&, pair<int, int> &)` is not a valid type for  a class member, but `bool (*)(pair<int, int>&, pair<int, int> &)` is.

Answer (score 2):

`decltype(cmp)` is a function type.

For standard library containers, the `Compare` type (if one exists) must be *Swappable*. Functions cannot be swapped, so they are ruled out. That is to say, when two containers are swapped, the comparator types follow the objects themselves into their new containers. This isn't possible for function types, thus the swappability requirement implicitly forbids function types from being used as comparators.

In many contexts, function types implicitly decay to function pointer types, which can make us forget that they're different types. This is one of the situations where the difference is relevant. You can use a function *pointer* as a container comparator - the container will store a copy of that pointer internally, and it gets swapped when the container is swapped. You can't use a function.

Comment: You can use a reference to a function as well, with `decltype((cmp))`

Comment: @cigien I don't think so. References to functions also fail to be *Swappable*. It seems that references to objects are allowed (but I'm not sure whether that's intentional).

Comment: Seems to [compile](https://godbolt.org/z/PadPeq) at least.

Comment: "*the Compare type (if one exists) must be Swappable*" More than that, `Compare` [must be a](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare) `FunctionObject`, which as the name suggests, [must be an object type](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/FunctionObject). So it's not really about swapping.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think the explicit requirement to be an object type is only present in the algorithms clause, not the containers clause.

Comment: @Brian: [26.2.6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/associative.reqmts#2) explicitly makes reference to the algorithms chapter, specifically to the section which defines `Compare` as a "function object type". Furthermore, 26.2.6 goes on to explicitly say, "*The object of type `Compare`*" In order for there to be an object of a type, that type must be an object type. `Compare` is an object type. So there's no reason to expect that `Compare` in one section would mean something different from another section.

Comment: @NicolBolas Well, to be very pedantic, this only proves that `Compare` must be an object type in the associative container case; the possibility of object reference types isn't ruled out for container adaptors. I'm about 90% sure that it was *intended* that it's always an object type, I just think the text doesn't make it clear.

Comment: @Brian: To interpret it that way, you have to assume that the specification will redefine every named requirement in every place it gets used. That's just not how they work. Uses of them in the text frequently refer to the definition of them (even if that definition comes *later*). Saying that `Compare` in one place is a different concept from `Compare` in another is like saying that "expression" refers to a different piece of grammar just because it's not in the [expr] section of the standard where that term is explicitly defined.

Comment: @NicolBolas `Compare` is not a named requirement, though, any more than `T` is. If some clause of the standard said "All the templates in this clause take a template parameter named `T`. `T` is an object type", you wouldn't infer that `T` means an object type in the rest of the library as well. But that's precisely what you're doing with `Compare` here.

Comment: @Brian: So, when the standard says, "an ordering relation `Compare` that induces a [strict weak ordering](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/alg.sorting) on elements of `Key`," and it links directly to a description of "strict weak ordering" that details the behavior of a thing called `Compare`, you need to be explicitly told that these two things that just so happen to have the same name, and one *directly linked to the other*, are the same?

Comment: @NicolBolas Of course not. I certainly agree that `Compare` must be an object in the case of an associative container - the requirement is incorporated by reference. There does not seem to be any link, however, in the case of `std::priority_queue`.

Comment: @NicolBolas "Each associative container is parameterized on `Key` and an ordering relation `Compare` that ..."

Comment: @Brian: "*There does not seem to be any link, however, in the case of std::priority_queue.*" You mean, [except for the last sentence of the *first paragraph* of `std::priority_queue`'s specification, right](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/priority.queue#1)? Or the [definition of every constructor in the class](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/priqueue.cons).

Comment: @NicolBolas That sentence you're referring to says "function or function object", so I have to read it as a requirement only on the particular entity that is the comparator, rather than on the type `Compare` required to be passed to the template in order to enable that comparator to be used (which, as we agree, may not be a function type).